# STM32 Timer Input Frequency Configuration (PCLKx_Timer)

Tags: embedded, stm32, bare-metal

I have an issue configuring the timer frequency input. I did read over the reference manual a couple of times and afterwards searched through the web to find an solution.

```cpp
template <uintptr_t BASE>
void hsi_config(Config config) {
    auto base = reinterpret_cast<volatile RCC_TypeDef *>(BASE);
    base->CR |= RCC_CR_HSION;
    while (!(base->CR & RCC_CR_HSIRDY))
        ;

    // config flash latency
    FLASH->ACR |= config.ahb_flash_latency;

    // for now always use TIMPRE = 0
    base->DCKCFGR1 &= ~RCC_DCKCFGR1_TIMPRE;
    base->CFGR |= (config.ahb_prescaler << 4U) | (config.apb1_prescaler << 10U) | (config.apb2_prescaler << 13U);

    // config PLL
    base->PLLCFGR = 0;
    base->PLLCFGR |= (config.pllm << 0U) | (config.plln << 6U) | (RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLSRC_HSI << 22U) | (config.pllp << 16U) | (config.pllq << 24U);

    // activate PLL
    base->CR |= RCC_CR_PLLON;
    while (!(base->CR & RCC_CR_PLLRDY))
        ;

    // Change HSI to PLL
    base->CFGR &= ~RCC_CFGR_SW;
    base->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_SW_PLL;
    while ((base->CFGR & RCC_CFGR_SWS) != RCC_CFGR_SWS_PLL)
        ;
}
```

With example the following values:

```
hsi = 16MHz
pllm = 8 
plln = 96
pllp = 2

=> sysclk = ((16MHz / 8) * 96) / 2 = 96MHz

ahb_prescaler = 1 
=> hclk = 96MHz

apb1_prescaler = 2 
=> pckl1 = 48MHz
=> pclk1_timer = pclk1 * 2 (As apb1 != 1 and TIMPRE = 0) (Rule from TIMPRE Register)
```

As a simple app to validate the frequency I used a timer which just counts to 1000 and then reloads.

```
Input 96MHz 
PSC = 47999 => 2KHz frequency
ARR = 2000 => Overflow once a second
```

However I get an overflow after 3 seconds => the timer is not at 96MHz but at 32MHz.

I also checked that with other configurations like pclk1_timer = 48MHz it always seems that the timer input is at 32MHz. (Overflow then happens after 1.5s)

Am I missing something in my configuration?

Comment: which stm32 they have different pll blocks.

Comment: for one that looks similar source/m needs to be between 4 and 16, you have 2. 2*96 = 192 which on mine needs to be less than 344 so thats fine. 344/2 = 96.  what timer are you using?  how many bits does it have in the counter?

Comment: if it is source/m then no reason to expect the pll to lock and/or it could lock at a strange frequency and depending on luck and environment might lock at different frequencies each power cycle or cold soak then power on.  would help to know which mcu this is.

Comment: what clock are you running to start with (why are you starting hsi?  why not switching to hsi or disabling the pll, etc).

Comment: It's a stm32f767zi eval board (Nucleo). So the Base frequency of HSI is 16MHz.

I think the output of m has to be in range from 1MHZ to 2MHZ so pllm of 8 should be fine (2MHz)

the output of plln (vco) must be within 100 and 432 mhz (2 * 96) = 192MHZ so should also be fine.

After that I use pllp = 2 therefore generating a sysclk of 96MHz

I actually checked the values with CubeMX CC tool. to be 100% sure I didn't have any bad timer configuration

Comment: > what clock are you running to start with (why are you starting hsi? why not switching to hsi or disabling the pll, etc)

Yea thats true. It's something I'll definetly need to change ! Thanks for that.

Atm it is the first thing in main. so even the `hsi start` could be ommited

Comment: @old_timer What I forgot to answer. I'm using a (Not advanced) Timer. So PSC / ARR is 16-Bits

Comment: yeah I wish their documentation was complete and consistent, each one has bits of info in different places if any...

Comment: m is fine in this one so thats not it.

Comment: n is fine thats not it

Comment: p is fine too, so nothing obvious then.  thought I had a simple answer,

Comment: But is there another register I may need to set ?
Or is this usally whats set when changing the frequency?

I'll try to check out the Sysclk in MCO and see which frequency it has